# Strange behaviour while returning something from void function

Tags: c++

```
void f() {
  return delete new int;
}
void f2() {
  return f();
}
```

Why such code is correct? I can return `void` expressions from `void` function. It's outrage to common sense.

In this case, did the С++ designers foresee, how to benefit from this?

Comment: Underneath the hubristic presentation lies a good question. +std::round(0.5)

Comment: `void f() { return void(); }` is less outrageous.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it an outrage to common sense?

There are other cases too: `throw` with no argument is a *nullary* operator of `void` type. It means you can write

```
condition ? something() : throw;
```

in a `catch` block. It is occasionally useful - it also helps with generic programming - why disallow things just because they are mentally taxing?